# Can i embed a PDF in an MVC View and use javascript to post the filled out form back to the server?

Tags: pdf, model-view-controller

My goal is to put a fillable PDF Form into a webpage, allow a user to fill it out, and post the results back to the server.  Does anybody know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You will need to embed JavaScript to your form so it will be sent to the backend. Here is a link to Acrobat: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/javascript.html

If you don't feel like doing it yourself there are third party tools that can do this.

Comment: Would there be any way outside of the pdf? somehow get the content of the embedded pdf to post?

        var pdf = $('#myPDF')
        var pdfData = '"pdfData" : "' + pdf + '"';

        $.ajax({
            ajaxStart: function () {
                $('#savingDialog').dialog('open')
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/UploadPDF',
            data: '{' + pdfData + '}',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            },
            complete: function () {
                debugger;
            }
        });

    }

Comment: Thanks for your advice btw, any names on those 3rd party tools?

Comment: This won't work, because the form is PDF, and it is self-contained, and it has its own form handling mechanism. However, you won't necessarily need JavaScript in the form itself, as it provides a Submit to URL action. In this action, you can select which protocol to be used. In your case, HTML POST method would probably be the most suitable, because the data coming back to the back end has the same structure as if it came from a web form.